# Error facing while mocking runtime for unit testing

Tags: substrate-node-template, unit-tests, mock

Here is the error I am seeing:

```rust
type mismatch resolving <sp_core::sr25519::Public as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId == u64
--> pallets/src/mock.rs:76:2
|
76 | type Public = <Signature as Verify>::Signer;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected u64, found struct
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a type mis-configuration here. As the compiler is hinting at you, in one place, you have said that the `AccountId` type should be `u64`, whereas somewhere else, you are using a more complex signature structure.

You must pick and use just one of these types for your `AccountId`.

If you want to use a `u64`, I suggest you look at the simple `mock.rs` file generated for the `substrate-node-template` example:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node-template/pallets/template/src/mock.rs

If you want to use a more complex public key for the `AccountId`, you can look at the `parallel` example:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/examples/parallel/src/tests.rs#L55